Why can't my STM32F401RCT6 output PWM?
main.c
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "tim.h"



int main(void) 
{
  PWM_Init();
    while(1)
    {
        TIM_SetCompare1(TIM3,1000);
        TIM_SetCompare2(TIM3,1000);
        TIM_SetCompare3(TIM3,1000);
        
    }

}



tim.c
#include "stm32f4xx.h" 
// Device header
    /**TIM3 GPIO Configuration
    PA6     ------> TIM3_CH1
    PA7     ------> TIM3_CH2
    PB0     ------> TIM3_CH3
    */
const uint16_t PWM_ARR = 466;
void PWM_Init()
{
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM3,ENABLE);
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA|RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB,ENABLE);
    
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructual;
    GPIO_InitStructual.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    GPIO_InitStructual.GPIO_OType =GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructual.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_7 | GPIO_Pin_6;
    GPIO_InitStructual.GPIO_PuPd =  GPIO_PuPd_UP;
    GPIO_InitStructual.GPIO_Speed =GPIO_Speed_100MHz ; 
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA,&GPIO_InitStructual);

    GPIO_InitStructual.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF; //
    GPIO_InitStructual.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructual.GPIO_Pin =GPIO_Pin_0 ;
    GPIO_InitStructual.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP ; //
    GPIO_InitStructual.GPIO_Speed= GPIO_Speed_100MHz; 
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB,&GPIO_InitStructual);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA,GPIO_PinSource6,GPIO_AF_TIM3);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA,GPIO_PinSource7,GPIO_AF_TIM3);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB,GPIO_PinSource0,GPIO_AF_TIM3); 
    
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_InitSturctural;
    TIM_InitSturctural.TIM_ClockDivision =0 ;
    TIM_InitSturctural.TIM_CounterMode =TIM_CounterMode_Up   ;
    TIM_InitSturctural.TIM_Period =2800-1;//ARR
    TIM_InitSturctural.TIM_Prescaler =0;//PSC
    TIM_InitSturctural.TIM_RepetitionCounter =0;
    
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM3,&TIM_InitSturctural);
    
    
    TIM_OCInitTypeDef TIMOC_InitSturctural;
    TIMOC_InitSturctural.TIM_OCMode =TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
    TIMOC_InitSturctural.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_High;
    TIMOC_InitSturctural.TIM_OutputState =TIM_OutputNState_Enable;
    TIMOC_InitSturctural.TIM_Pulse =0;//CCR
    
    TIM_OC1Init(TIM3,&TIMOC_InitSturctural);
    TIM_OC1PreloadConfig(TIM3,TIM_OCPreload_Enable);
    
    TIM_OC2Init(TIM3,&TIMOC_InitSturctural);
    TIM_OC2PreloadConfig(TIM3,TIM_OCPreload_Enable);
    
    TIM_OC3Init(TIM3,&TIMOC_InitSturctural);
    TIM_OC3PreloadConfig(TIM3,TIM_OCPreload_Enable);
    
    TIM_ARRPreloadConfig(TIM3, ENABLE);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM3,ENABLE);
    
}

My teammates and I have checked for half a day and still haven't found what configuration error is causing the PWM not to output. I hope someone who has encountered this problem before can help me solve it. Thank you.

Why not even blink a LED first? Do you have a debugger you can single step code?

causing the PWM not to output ... what does it output? ... please update your post ... do not write a comment

why are you requiring someone with previous experience to help with the solution?

TIMOC_InitSturctural.TIM_OutputState =TIM_OutputNState_Enable;
should be changed to:
TIMOC_InitSturctural.TIM_OutputState =TIM_OutputState_Enable;
Finally found it
